# Time-based triggers on global window in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm looking for clear documentation and/or and example on how to setup a time-based trigger on a global window in Apache beam.

The purpose is to perform a count of the events since the last trigger fired, even when 0 events have been added since.

Answer (score 2):

You can use timers and state, if you need to use global window and emit result even if there was no event since the last firing. I think it is not possible to do it with the built in triggers.

You can keep the count in a state and use a timer to emit the results periodically. 
These two blog post explains the usage of timers and state:

[Stateful processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html)

[Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html)

Comment: Do you know if there is a working example of timely and stateful processing? I can't seem to be able to get it to work (python).

Comment: 3 years later and there's still not full examples - driving me insane.